# Creating an about me and profile image problems?

Tags: php, database, social-networking

I get this error on a university project i'm working on. Each user has a profile in which they can upload a 'profile image' and  create an 'about me'. However when you try to submit any profile information the error occurs... Any ideas?

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

These are the two PHP files related with the error...

rnprofile.php...

```
 <?php // rnprofile.php
include_once 'rnheader.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
    die("<br /><br />You need to login to view this page");
$user = $_SESSION['user'];

echo "<h3>Edit your Profile</h3>";



$UserData = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `rnprofiles` WHERE `user` = '$user'"));//Grabbing all info on the user
//print_r($UserData);
$UserExists = ($UserData!=null) ? true : false; // Seeing if the user exists (returns true if so, false if not

/*if ($UserExists==false) {
    echo "we don't exist";
    exit();
}*/

?>
</br>

<div id="container_profile">

<?php

if (isset($_POST['about']))
{
    $about = sanitizeString($_POST['about']);
    $about = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $about);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM rnprofiles WHERE user='$user'";
    if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)))
    {
        queryMysql("UPDATE rnprofiles SET text='$about' where user='$user'");
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO rnprofiles VALUES('$user', '$about')";
        queryMysql($query);
    }
}
else
{
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM rnprofiles WHERE user='$user'";
    $result = queryMysql($query);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        $row  = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $about = stripslashes($row[4]);
    }
    else $about = "";
}

$about = stripslashes(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $about));

if (isset($_FILES['profile']['name']))
{
    $saveto = "$user.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'], $saveto);
    $typeok = TRUE;

    switch($_FILES['profile']['type'])
    {
        case "profile/gif":   $src = imagecreatefromgif($saveto); break;

        case "profile/jpeg":  // Both regular and progressive jpegs
        case "profile/pjpeg":   $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($saveto); break;

        case "profile/png":   $src = imagecreatefrompng($saveto); break;

        default:            $typeok = FALSE; break;
    }

    if ($typeok)
    {
        list($w, $h) = getimagesize($saveto);
        $max = 600;
        $tw  = $w;
        $th  = $h;

        if ($w > $h && $max < $w)
        {
            $th = $max / $w * $h;
            $tw = $max;
        }
        elseif ($h > $w && $max < $h)
        {
            $tw = $max / $h * $w;
            $th = $max;
        }
        elseif ($max < $w)
        {
            $tw = $th = $max;
        }

        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($tw, $th);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tw, $th, $w, $h);
        imageconvolution($tmp, array( // Sharpen image
                                array(-1, -1, -1),
                                array(-1, 16, -1),
                                array(-1, -1, -1)
                               ), 8, 0);
        imagejpeg($tmp, $saveto);
        imagedestroy($tmp);
        imagedestroy($src);
    }
}

Profile($user);

echo <<<_END
<form method='post' action='rnprofile.php'
    enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Enter or edit your details and/or upload an image:<br />
<textarea name='about' cols='40' rows='3'>$about</textarea>
Image: <input type='file' name='profile' size='1' maxlength='32' />
<input type='submit' value='Save Profile' />
</pre></form>
_END;
```

rnfunctions.php...

```
function Profile($user)
{
    if (file_exists("$user.jpg"))
        echo "<p><a title='' class='fancybox' href='$user.jpg'><img src='$user.jpg' border='1' align='left' height='200' width='200' alt=''/></a></p>";
        echo "</br>";

    $result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM rnprofiles WHERE user='$user'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        echo stripslashes($row[2]) . "<br clear=left /><br />";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like the problem is here:

```
"INSERT INTO rnprofiles VALUES('$user', '$about')"
```

The query should be in the form:

```
"INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES('$column1value', '$column2value')"
```

Although I didn't have time to look over your whole code.